# How to Find the path of an recently opened/ Currently Active file with a Mouse pointer in it using c#

Tags: c#, file

I want to find the pah for the currently opened file which is either currently active in the windows Explorer . i have got the location for the folder while the folder is being clicked but how do we get the path of the file like a text file or word or something like that

```
private string GetActiveWindowPath()
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
            int handleint = int.Parse(handle + "");
            SHDocVw.ShellWindows explorer = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();

            //var xy = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium();

            var xpl = explorer.Cast<SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium>().Where(hwnd => hwnd.HWND == handleint).FirstOrDefault();
            if (xpl != null)
            {
                // this will get the folder location
                string path = new Uri(xpl.LocationURL).LocalPath;
                return ("location:" + xpl.LocationName + " path:" + path );
            }
            return "HWND" + handleint ;
        }
```

[image]

[image]

i ma getting the path of the opened window as you see but not the text file

Comment: System.IO.Path is not enough?

Comment: What do you mean by "**the** currently opened file"? Note that at any given time, Windows and programs running in it has *many* files open.

Comment: currently opened file which is Active

Comment: What do you mean by "active"? Active how?

Comment: say double clicking on the text file or one that has the mouse pointer in it

Comment: Try to rewite the question - the text of your question is misleading and does not correspond with the code provided. Do you need to get path of the file over wihich mouse cursor hovers in Windows Explorer?

Comment: An individual window's current contents may be the result of loading 10s or possibly hundreds of files  which all contribute, in some small way (e.g. a browser has loaded html, css, javascript from multiple files that all produce the final appearance of what's on screen). There's not a concept in Windows (or pretty well any OS) that any given window (or set of mouse coordinates) is tied in some way to **one** particular file. What **problem** are you trying to solve where you thought that this was part of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private string GetMainModuleFilepath(int processId)
    {
        string wmiQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processId;
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
        {
            using (var results = searcher.Get())
            {
                ManagementObject mo = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (mo != null)
                {
                    return (string)mo["CommandLine"];
                }
            }
        }
        Process testProcess = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        return null;
    }
```

After that you will get Executable file name with your file name like

"c:..\notepade.exe" D:\New Folder\sampleFile.txt" after that split as you like to get the path.